# Maximize sum of ceiling functions

Tags: elementary-number-theory, optimization, integer-partitions

I need to find the maximum of a sum of ceiling functions. The following are given
$$N,C\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ with }0\leq N\text{ and }1\leq C$$
$$\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}\text{ with }p,q \text{ coprime and } p\geq q\geq 1$$

Maximize

$$\sum_{i=1}^k{\Bigl\lceil a_i\frac{p}{q} \Bigr\rceil}$$

where $a_i$ is a partition of $N$ with $k$ terms and $k\leq \min(N,C)$.

I only need the maximum value, not the partition of $N$.
My first idea was to let $k=\min(N,C)$ and take $k\lceil \frac{Np}{kq}\rceil$ as the max. But I think that's wrong for some inputs.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
An answer might be $k=\min{(N,C)}$, $a_1=N-\max{(0,k-1)}$, then $a_i=1$ for $i>1$?

Comment: Are there any more restraints on $p$ and $q$?  Do we know $p < q$, say?

Comment: I have updated the question to reflect that $p \geq q$